# SQL command doesn't invoke the specific query

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I have 2 tables one is with replies and second with added friends. Both tables have fields of ids of the friend ( receiver ) and the reply poster. I inner join these tables on receiver_id and added_friend where username in 'friends' is $_SESSION['user'] ( the logged person ). All I receive after the query are just replies ( both parties see them ) and cannot query the reply back ( both parties cannot see the other's replies ) why is that so ? The code seems to be logical...Thanks a lot.

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(128) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `added_friend` varchar(128) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `friendname` varchar(128) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

   --

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reply` (
  `rep_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `reply_comm` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `reply_poster` varchar(128) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `reply_poster_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_name` varchar(128) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply_date` date default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rep_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

The structure looks like that:

Table 'friends' :

```
          username | added_friend
          =====================
          mike     | 10
          rob      | 20
```

Table 'reply' :

```
          reply_poster | receiver_id
          =========================
          mike     | 20
          rob      | 10  <- added friend id
```

The PHP SQL command is this:

```
        $repcheck2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM reply INNER JOIN friends ON  
        receiver_id  = added_friend  WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ORDER BY rep_id  
        DESC ");
```

So both parties should see replies and posts when logged in ( $_SESSION['user']) but cannot see the replies back only their own posting replies / comments. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I'd watch just putting raw session data into a query like that. It needs to be cleaned before it goes to the database to prevent MYSQL injection.

Also, personally I'd do the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `reply`, `friends` WHERE `friends`.`receiver_id`=`reply`.`added_friend` AND `friends`.`username`='".$_SESSION['user']."' ORDER BY `replies`.`rep_id` DESC
```

It's much easier to understand than inner joins and the possibility for ambiguity (i.e. no specific table name mentioned on each field).

Not sure if that will fix your problem, but we'll see.

If it doesn't can you tell me what it does output? I.e. does it output any rows form the database, or any errors?

Comment: This one is correct ( WHERE `reply`.`receiver_id`=`friends`.`added_friend` ) mind the small mistakes in your answer. Apart from that, nope it doesn't work. I mean the other part cannot see my reply..

Comment: Thing is this: When I get rid of $_SESSION - the problem vanishes and the replies can bee seen - but then ALL replies are seen even these which are not sent to the specific user - that's why I used $_SESSION which filters the replies - strangely it doesn't work..but submits correctly posts ( I mean both parties can see their own replies not the receiver's reply )